# Loop a Create type as table argument in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm developing a stored procedure to insert a set of codes inside a table. I'm working with SQL SERVER 2012 SP1 Express edition.

I've done this to pass an array to the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ChildsCodeList
AS TABLE
(
  CODE nvarchar(20)
);
GO
```

And this is my stored procedure:

```
create procedure dbo.MyStoredProdure
    @childs as dbo.ChildsCodeList READONLY,
    @parentCode nvarchar(20)
as
begin

[ ... ]

end
go
```

How can I loop `@childs`?

I have to insert that code inside a table with an incremental value but in this case I can't use an identity column.

I'm going to insert those codes in this table:

```
  CODE   |  POSITION
---------+----------
         |
```

Comment: SELECT CODE FROM @childs; is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. I have to insert that code inside a table with an incremental value but in this case I can't use an identity column.

Comment: Probably, I can use this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111401/es.

Comment: are you looking for a row number along with  codes from @childs and insert these two column values in somw table?

Comment: @Deepshikha Yes, that's it. I have to insert childs code and position on `@childs` in the same row at the same table.

Comment: What Sql Server Version you are on ? 2008 ? 2012?

Comment: @M.Ali SQL SERVER 2012 SP1 Express.

Comment: Have a look at the new function `Sequence` in sql server 2012 this [`ANSWER`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894079/mainting-identity-value-across-multiple-tables/23894285#23894285) is one scenario where it was useful, maybe it can do the trick for you too, H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write as:

```
CREATE PROCedure dbo.MyStoredProdure
    @childs as dbo.ChildsCodeList READONLY
    AS    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO tbl_test
    -- since no ordering is to be done among rows use 'Select 1'
    SELECT CODE,row_number() over (order by (select 1 )) as Rownum
    FROM   @childs

GO
```

You can find a detailed step by step [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/50ef3/10) here.

Answer (score 0):

with `row_number()`, probably.

```
insert sometable (code, position)
select code, row_Number() over (order by something) from  @childs
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand it completely. My codes aren't ordered. Why do I have to use `order by` with row_number()?

Comment: @VansFannel because you want incremental numbers. They are by definition, an order

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. It orders my codes and I don't want them ordered. I have to insert them in the same order that they are in `@childs`.

Comment: @VansFannel Data **doesn't have** an order. Any order in your data is purely coincidental

Comment: `(order by something)` order my data.